# how to slice a 2d array based on indices given in another 2d array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, array-broadcasting, numpy-slicing

I have an `MxN` array called `A` which stores the data I want. I have another `M x N2` array `B` which stores array indices, and `N2<N`. Each row of `B` stores the indices of the elements I want to get from A for that row. For example, the following code works for me:

```
A_reduced = np.zeros((M,N2))
for i in range(M):
    A_reduced[i,:] = A[i,B[i,:]]
```

Are there any 'vectorized' ways to extract the desired elements from `A` based on `B` instead of looping through each row?

Comment: Just clarifying. let's say A_reduced is `[0, 0, 0]` and B is `[1, 2]`. Would you expect A_reduced to now be `[0, 0]`

Comment: Why do you want to vectorize it? Do you think it'll make the code run faster or is there a different reason? If you want to make it easy to read you can do something like `A_reduced[i,:] = [A[i,B[i,:]] for i in range(M)]`. I think numpy has a vectorize class but that might overcomplicate: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html

Answer (score 1):

You can exploit array indexing and use reshape:

```
# set up M=N=4, N2=2
a = np.arange(16).reshape(4,4)
b = np.array([[1,2],[0,1],[2,3],[1,3]])

row_idx = np.repeat(np.arange(b.shape[0]),b.shape[1])
col_idx = b.ravel()

# output:
a[row_idx, col_idx].reshape(b.shape)
```

Output:

```
array([[ 1,  2],
       [ 4,  5],
       [10, 11],
       [13, 15]])
```

---

**Update**: Another similar solution

```
row_idx = np.repeat(np.arange(b.shape[0]),b.shape[1]).reshape(b.shape)

# output
a[row_idx,b]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [203]: A = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)                                                               
In [204]: B = np.array([[0,2],[1,3],[3,0]])
```

Your row iteration:

```
In [207]: A_reduced = np.zeros((3,2),int)                                                              
In [208]: for i in range(3): 
     ...:     A_reduced[i,:] = A[i, B[i,:]] 
     ...:                                                                                              
In [209]: A_reduced                                                                                    
Out[209]: 
array([[ 0,  2],
       [ 5,  7],
       [11,  8]])
```

A 'vectorized' version:

```
In [210]: A[np.arange(3)[:,None], B]                                                                   
Out[210]: 
array([[ 0,  2],
       [ 5,  7],
       [11,  8]])
```

and streamlined with a newish function:

```
In [212]: np.take_along_axis(A,B,axis=1)                                                               
Out[212]: 
array([[ 0,  2],
       [ 5,  7],
       [11,  8]])
```